# "onClick" on external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to Javascript and I'm triyng to perform an onClick event on an image in a external .js file using the html tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="embed.js">
```

The code inside "embed.js" is the following

```
var image1=new Image();
image1.src="img.gif"
document.write('<IMG src='+image1.src+'>');


$(document).ready( function()
{
 $(image1).click( function()
{
    alert("Hello World");
    });
});
```

As you can see, I'd like to show an alert when somebody click on the image, but the code I've posted doesn't work. Could you help me? Thanks! :)

@JD it the html code is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>
<script src="embed.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: `= new Image()` is your problem here.. it should be a selector.. $('#image1') maybe? post your html./

Comment: PS. Don't use `document.write()`.

Comment: @JFit: OP wants to *create* an image and add a listener, not add a listener to an existing image.

Comment: `document.write` is bad practice. [Reasons.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

The image that you attach the `onclick` to and the image that you put on the page are not the same.

*Explanation:* The string that you pass to `document.write` is parsed by the browser to create a *new* image element (albeit one that has the same `src`) while `image1` is a different image instance that is only in memory (not on the page), but it has the event listener.

To fix, replace

```
document.write('<IMG src='+image1.src+'>');
```

with

```
document.body.appendChild(image1);
```

Now you're dealing with only one image, which gets put on the page *and* the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are correct

but you can insert the "image1" object directly in the DOM.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    // Take care with the scope of image1

    var image1 = $("<img/>").attr("src","img.gif").appendTo("parentElementInDOMselector");

    image1.click( function(){
        alert("Hello World");
    });

});
```

You can use appendTo, preppendTo, or functions like html(); replace(); etc...

Answer (score -1):

Your selections are off, try:

```
$("document").ready( function()
{
 $("#image1").click( function()
{
    alert("Hello World");
    });
});
```

and add an id to the image tag

```
<img id='image1' ...
```

JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YS95J/

Comment: The OP wants to *create* an image and add a listener, not add a listener to an existing image.